# getting image size from folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, file-upload

Is there a way to get an image dimensions using javascript or jquery? I'm trying to get an image size from a folder on my server, but I can't use php since I have around 50+ images that need's to have the image dimension checked. Are there plugins or functions that I could use to get an image dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this plugin should help you :

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

```
$("#loaded_image").imagesLoaded(function(){
console.log( $(this).width() )
console.log( $(this).height() )
});
```

However if you want to get the info before you load the image using PHP , then refer to here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: I might use getimagesize instead, since I kinda scale down the images when I load them.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code available in internet

```
<?php

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image_name.jpg");

echo "Image width " .$width;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image height " .$height;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image type " .$type;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Attribute " .$attr;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(function()
{
    console.log(this.width());
    console.log(this.height());
});
```